# Bad Request with STS in minio

Tags: java, minio, sts

I am trying to get a temporary access id and access secret from minio with AssumeRole SDK in java.
the problem is I could get the correct access key and access secret from minio response with aws client.
but it always fails with the java sdk.

here is the steps:

1. I run the "asw sts " command.

```
aws --profile test2 --endpoint-url 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9090' sts assume-role --policy '{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [{"Effect": "Allow","Action": ["s3:GetObject"],"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]}]}'  --role-arn 'arn:aws:s3:::videos/*'  --role-session-name anything
```

and I get the following response:

```
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "19IUI91YA5P2BZ7D2B4X",
        "SecretAccessKey": "ceFxfvA26Yd6I7r+FlsWc7H3k0U+wswNqwAbaANy",
        "SessionToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY2Nlc3NLZXkiOiIxOUlVSTkxWUE1UDJCWjdEMkI0WCIsImV4cCI6MTY2OTcxNTIxMiwicGFyZW50IjoidGVzdDIiLCJzZXNzaW9uUG9saWN5IjoiZXlKV1pYSnphVzl1SWpvZ0lqSXdNVEl0TVRBdE1UY2lMQ0pUZEdGMFpXMWxiblFpT2lCYmV5SkZabVpsWTNRaU9pQWlRV3hzYjNjaUxDSkJZM1JwYjI0aU9pQmJJbk16T2tkbGRFOWlhbVZqZENKZExDSlNaWE52ZFhKalpTSTZJRnNpWVhKdU9tRjNjenB6TXpvNk9pb2lYWDFkZlE9PSJ9.vUYGsldkiuM1ukuTvjgHY9PYSI7f_sDrkQYUcgBX37Z1ymTudoFE71E_6Y0G5p2qif3KS-_a3rbUSUlcd21ojw",
        "Expiration": "2022-11-29T09:46:52+00:00"
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "Arn": ""
    }
}
```

with the sdk, the code is like :

```
  * minio
         */
            String policy = "{\n" +
                    "    \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\n" +
                    "    \"Statement\": [\n" +
                    "        {\n" +
                    "            \"Effect\": \"Allow\",\n" +
                    "            \"Action\": [\n" +
                    "                \"s3:*\",\n" +
                    "            ],\n" +
                    "            \"Resource\": [\n" +
                    "                \"arn:aws:s3:::*\"\n" +
                    "            ]\n" +
                    "        },\n" +
                    "    ]\n" +
                    "}";
            try {
            
            
                AssumeRoleProvider provider = new AssumeRoleProvider(
                        endpoint, accessKey, secretKey, 3600, policy
                        , "", "arn:aws:s3:::videos/*", "anything", null, null
                );
                Credentials credentials = provider.fetch();
                System.out.println("accessKey:" + credentials.accessKey());
                System.out.println("secretKey:" + credentials.secretKey());
                System.out.println("sessionToken:" + credentials.sessionToken());
     
                System.out.println(credentials.isExpired());
                System.out.println("Credentials ok");
     
     
                
                StaticProvider staticProvider = new StaticProvider(credentials.accessKey(), credentials.secretKey(), credentials.sessionToken());
                //StaticProvider staticProvider = new StaticProvider("QO43SYZ8342SKBFRCB0N", "XHkepy+rphje0i9j6iIZjuFaVOj1rWG6+8fCrfZ4", 
               //       "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY2Nlc3NLZXkiOiJRTzQzU1laODM0MlNLQkZSQ0IwTiIsImV4cCI6MTY2OTcxMDI5NiwicGFyZW50IjoidGVzdDIiLCJzZXNzaW9uUG9saWN5IjoiZXlKV1pYSnphVzl1SWpvaU1qQXhNaTB4TUMweE55SXNJbE4wWVhSbGJXVnVkQ0k2VzNzaVUybGtJam9pVTNSdGRERWlMQ0pGWm1abFkzUWlPaUpCYkd4dmR5SXNJa0ZqZEdsdmJpSTZJbk16T2lvaUxDSlNaWE52ZFhKalpTSTZJbUZ5YmpwaGQzTTZjek02T2pvcUluMWRmUT09In0.FvlR-Qm4-bJCF1vaeGNVqm5keCA1zsRfnjCW0NcLanYuBy8BW9NOwKxfe8v7RZekFJKjOUWdVxbygcLlAuCP-A");
                MinioClient minioClient = MinioClient.builder().endpoint(endpoint).credentialsProvider(staticProvider).build();
                File file = new File("~\aaa.png");
                
                String objectName = "aaa.png";
                try {
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    minioClient.putObject(PutObjectArgs.builder().bucket("videos")
                            .object(objectName)
                            .contentType("image/png")
                            .stream(fileInputStream, fileInputStream.available(), -1).build());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("finished");
     
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and the response is :

```
java.security.ProviderException: STS service failed with HTTP status code 400
    at io.minio.credentials.AssumeRoleBaseProvider.fetch(AssumeRoleBaseProvider.java:85)
    at org.darebeat.MinIODemo2.main(MinIODemo2.java:48)
```

any idea on this error ?